# Работа с csv формирование таблиц Python

Tags: python

Час добрый!
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сформировать  [следующую таблицу](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-5MbfNSWoTjMd9iKUUUCH_Rdx1eXgqd0gJzPRqa6VI/edit#gid=0) при помощи Python?

Вижу примерно так (сама таблица):

```
            user_dump = {
                "Channel": title,
                "About": description,
                "Links": {
                    "link#1",
                    "link#2",
                },

                "video_links": {
                    "link#1",
                    "link#2",
                },

                "data": {
                    "data#1"
                    "data#2"
                },
                "video_description": {
                    "description#1"
                    "description#2"
                }
            }
```

Дальше ее просто наполнять на каждом новом проходе по каналам. Единственный вопрос, как записать список ссылок, чтобы в таблице они были каждая в новой строке, а не все в одной?

Comment: Тебе группировка записей нужна. pandas тебе в помощь.

Comment: Что вы называете "таблицей"? у вас в итоге получается не то недословарь, не то недоjson.

Comment: Если бы знал как нужно сделать правильно, то явно бы не обращался сюда. 
@Namerek Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: @Дмитрий, в каком формате у вас входные данные? `user_dump` - это пример входных данных или это уже после обработки?

Comment: @MaxU Входные данные просто лежат в переменных.
Название канала, его описание - переменные с одним элементом. \
Ссылки с описания - список из n ссылок. \
Ссылки на видео - список из n ссылок.\
Описания и дата, такой же список из n элементов.\ 
Все данные получаются поэтапно: информация с профиля - список видео - информация по каждому видео

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, проще всего здесь будет воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html).

Сначала надо будет подготовить данные в виде списка списков, чтобы получилась таблица:

```
data = [
  ["channel_name_1", "channel_description_1", "video1_link", "video1_date", "video1_desc"],
  ["channel_name_1", "channel_description_1", "video2_link", "video2_date", "video2_desc"],
  ["channel_name_1", "channel_description_1", "video3_link", "video3_date", "video3_desc"],
  ["channel_name_2", "channel_description_2", "video1_link", "video1_date", "video1_desc"],
  ["channel_name_2", "channel_description_2", "video2_link", "video2_date", "video2_desc"],
]
```

после этого можно создать Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["channel","chnl_desc","video_link","video_date","video_desc"])
```

результат:

```
In [141]: df
Out[141]:
          channel              chnl_desc   video_link   video_date   video_desc
0  channel_name_1  channel_description_1  video1_link  video1_date  video1_desc
1  channel_name_1  channel_description_1  video2_link  video2_date  video2_desc
2  channel_name_1  channel_description_1  video3_link  video3_date  video3_desc
3  channel_name_2  channel_description_2  video1_link  video1_date  video1_desc
4  channel_name_2  channel_description_2  video2_link  video2_date  video2_desc
```

далее этот DataFrame можно сохранить в Excel файл:

```
df.set_index(["channel","chnl_desc"]).to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!